# Uploading images

Tags: file-uploads

I am unable to upload images to my site. I haven't made any significant changes to it lately and was able to successfully do it before. How can this be fixed please?

Comment: Your question is terribly sparse on info. What happens when you try to upload images? What kind of field are you uploading into? In the control panel or through a front-end form? Do you get an error message? If so, what is it? What version of EE are you running?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reasons are:

- Upload path not valid - Fix under content > upload preferences
- Cannot write to folder - Check folder exists and has 777 permissions